# TCP passthroughs is not working for 80 port

Tags: tcp, haproxy

Hi I'm trying to implement use TCP passthrough based on SNI. It works for SSL but it's not working for 80.

configuration is below:

```
global
log         127.0.0.1 local2
chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
maxconn     4000
user        haproxy
group       haproxy
daemon
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
defaults
 timeout client 30s
 timeout server 30s
 timeout connect 5s

frontend https
 bind *:443
 mode tcp
 tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
 tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
 acl mytonicssl req_ssl_sni -i staging.mytonic.com
 use_backend mytonic-ssl if mytonicssl


 backend mytonic-ssl
 mode tcp
 balance roundrobin
 stick-table type binary len 32 size 30k expire 30m
 acl clienthello req_ssl_hello_type 1
 acl serverhello rep_ssl_hello_type 2
 tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
 tcp-request content accept if clienthello
 tcp-response content accept if serverhello
 stick on payload_lv(43,1) if clienthello
 stick store-response payload_lv(43,1) if serverhello
 option ssl-hello-chk
 server server1 10.10.17.222:8443 check

 frontend http
 bind *:80
 mode tcp
 acl mytonic_http hdr_dom(host) -i staging.mytonic.com
 use_backend mytonic_nonssl if mytonic_http


 backend mytonic_nonssl
 mode tcp
 balance roundrobin
 server server1 10.10.17.222:8080 check
```

If i added default backend then it works. But this is not the virtual host solution. My haproxy version is: HA-Proxy version 1.5.18 2016/05/10 any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SNI is a TLS extension which contains the target hostname. Since it is a TLS extension it can only be used with SSL/TLS traffic. The matching mechanism with plain HTTP (i.e. no SSL/TLS) is the HTTP Host header. But to balance based on this header you need to use mode http (the default) and not mode tcp. See also [How to divert traffic based on hostname using HAProxy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/105824/how-to-divert-traffic-based-on-hostname-using-haproxy)